# How to !click one button when another is clicked angular 2?

Tags: angular, angular-directive, angular-template

I'm trying to !click on button when another is clicked, but couldn't make it work yet...

Here's my code HTML:

```
 <ion-row class="rowconfig">
<ion-col class="colconfig">
  <button ion-button clear small block [color]="!buttonClicked1 ? 'gray' : 'white'" (click)="isButtonToggle(1)">100 Enviadas</button>
</ion-col>
<ion-col>
  <button ion-button clear small block [color]="!buttonClicked2 ? 'gray' : 'white'" (click)="isButtonToggle(2)">50 Recebidas</button>
</ion-col>
```

And the TS:

```
 isButtonToggle(x):void{
    switch(x){
      case 1:
        this.buttonClicked1 = !this.buttonClicked1;
        break;
      case 2:
        this.buttonClicked2 = !this.buttonClicked2;
        break;
    }
  }
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Just bind to the `disabled` attribute on the button.

Comment: Fixed the post... I didn't mean disable, I meant !clicked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `[attr.disabled]`:

```
<button ion-button clear small block [color]="!buttonClicked1 ? 'gray' : 'white'" (click)="isButtonToggle(1)" [attr.disabled]="!buttonClicked1  ? true : null">100 Enviadas</button>
```

Comment: But I need the other button to be clickeable... this should work like a select, if one is clicked the other is !clicked and vice versa.

by using the disable I can't click it...

I just realised that I wrote "disable" in my post... sorry, fixing it now.

Answer (score 0):

I manage to solve my own problem lol

this is what I did:

In my page TS class I changed the "isButtonToggled" function to this:

```
isButtonToggle(x):void{
switch(x){
  case 1:
    this.buttonClicked1 = !this.buttonClicked1  
    if(this.buttonClicked2 = true){
        this.buttonClicked2 = !this.buttonClicked2;
    }
    break;
  case 2:
    this.buttonClicked2 = !this.buttonClicked2;
    if (this.buttonClicked1 = true){
        this.buttonClicked1 = !this.buttonClicked1;
    }
    break;
}
```

}